# Angular2 - better use angular-cli or clean prepared before biolerplate?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a question about using angular-cli. I had used it, but I had trouble with override webpack conf, sass files, assets conf. In other hand I have nice boilerplate with karma tests sass and other confs, which is enough for most projects. Which solution is better? angular-cli or spent some time and get own custom boilerplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a personal answer and every developer would have its own.

Mine is:

Angular-cli should be up to date with the latest things in Angular 2 while with your own build/compile process may not.

There is no problem in using your own set, but you can be out of date without even known and end missing some good features that angular-cli may have.

But you should use what you think is better for you and your project. Any option will work. Like I said, is more a personal opinion then a absolute truth.

Comment: Thaks for response, but how can I replace/extend default ng-cli webpack conf to add for example new webpack.DefinePlugil({}), or new loader or API_END_POINT?

Comment: API_END_POINT can be set in environment file, set up inside angular-cli.json, About webpack and loader you can see it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656

Comment: Thanks for answer mate, now I see that angular-cli is better choice.